# What does 事だ mean in this context?

Tags: grammar, meaning

The context:

> Speaker to himself: そこに行って彼に会えば全部分かる事だ

At first I thought the 事だ meant "should" but on second thought realized that meaning of 事だ actually indicates that you're advising or warning someone, and not that an outcome is to be expected. So then what does it mean? Does it mean something like　だろう in this context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, 事 makes a noun phrase:

> そこに行って彼に会えば全部分かる事
>
> what I can completely know if I go there and see him

Notice that the subject is omitted in your sentence. The subject may be **それ** (it). So the construction of the sentence is as simple as `(それは)～だ` (`It is ...`).

Lastly, I think こと instead of 事 is preferred when making a noun phrase.

Answer (score 3):

```
          ( adding to the good answer )
```

> (それは) そこに行って彼に会えば分かる事だ

( That matter is not as difficult as it seems, and so that ) 
if you (etc.) go there and see him, it is something (こと)  that will be clarified.

> "Hey, lad, it's really simple -- just a matter of going there and talking to him."

A similar expression is: 「〜すれば済むことだ」

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13145748978 
>   「彼らが私の家に来れば済むことだ。」 
>   Il suffit qu'ils viennent chez moi. 
>   Ils n'ont qu'à venir chez moi.

They only need to come to my house. (and it'll be all done)

I wonder if these expressions 
「〜すれば分かる事だ」
「〜すれば済むことだ」
are a result of some earlier components being dropped.

Answer (score 0):

The word 事 has several meanings.

Probably the closest meaning is the one below:
㋚（「…ことだ」などの形で）
話し手自身の判断に基づいた進言・忠告である意を表す。
An advice or warning based on the speaker's own judgement.
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/80340/meaning/m0u/%E4%BA%8B/

So the translation would be:
そこに行って彼に会えば全部分かる事だ。
I believe that if I go there and meet him, I will know everything.

Comment: この文は、「㋚話し手自身の判断に基づいた進言・忠告である意を表す。」ではないですね。なぜなら、 「㋚（「…ことだ」などの形で）話し手自身の判断に基づいた進言・忠告である意を表す。」の使い方は・・・　　○「そこに行って彼に**会うことだ。** 」(=会え。)　○「せいぜい**頑張ることだな**。」(＝頑張れ。)　　○「～～ **することだ** 。」(=「～しろ。」)   　 ×「～～すれば分かることだ」